# how to implement a login dialog box popping within the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to design a webpage login that when click on the login button a login box pops on the same page (not in a new window) while the page itself becomes "disabled".

I am stuck at how to start implementing this. I wonder if this can be done using jquery? Any suggestions would be apprecieted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you could use jquery ui dialog

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

like that :

```
    $( "#oneDiv" ).dialog({
        height: 140,
        modal: true
    });
```

You're oneDiv need to be at `display:none;` and you put whatever you want in it

Comment: You could create also your own pop up box using the jquery effects.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you have a lot of options for this. If you are OK with jQuery UI library just use their [dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) with modal option set to true.

There are also some lightweight options like [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)